# Unable to end the incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

i am implementing the functionality of call blocking. but i am getting exception when i call endCall() method.

```
W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10083 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony$Stub$Proxy.endCall(ITelephony.java:2025)
W/System.err:     at veclar.map.callandsmsblocking.PhoneStateReceiver.onReceive(PhoneStateReceiver.java:109)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3187)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1672)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

i have decalred the permissions in manifest and also calling explicitly in main activity but still i am getting some kind of permission error and didn't find any solution yet.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="veclar.map.callandsmsblocking">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
            <intent-filter android:priority="9999">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**PhoneStateReceiver.java**

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private String blockingNumber = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        ITelephony telephonyService;
        try {
            String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

                    m.setAccessible(true);
                    telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

                    if ((number.equals(blockingNumber))) {
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Ending the call from: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.i("App Update","call Ended: "+number);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Toast.makeText(context, "Ring " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("App Update","Ring "+number);

            }
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                m.setAccessible(true);
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);

                Toast.makeText(context, "Answered " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("App Update","Answered "+number);

                if ((number.equals(blockingNumber))) {
                    telephonyService.endCall();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Ending the call from: " + number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.i("App Update","call Ended: "+number);
                }
            }
            if(state.equalsIgnoreCase(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context, "Idle "+ number, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("App Update","Idle "+number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**ITelephony.java**

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;


public interface ITelephony {
    boolean endCall();
    void answerRingingCall();
    void silenceRinger();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
{
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    hello = findViewById(R.id.hello);
    hello.setText("WE are testing call and sms blocking. have patience");

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Permission is not granted
        requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, android.Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 10);
    }

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {

        case 10: {

            try {
                if (grantResults[0] == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && grantResults[1] == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) && grantResults[2] == (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION GRANTED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSION NOT GRANTED ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well, `"android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE"` does not equal `"android.permission.CALL_PHONE"`

Comment: @Michael problem solved. Thanks!

Comment: @JunaidBashir i am having same issue . can you tell me , how you solved it. It will be a great help